# How to reopen a form to update the datas with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, put, react-props

I'm setting up an admin panel to add, delete or edit a list of books. I have some problem with the update process. I guess I need to reopen the form with the data to edit some input and submit it to a put request with axios, but my first problem is how to reopen the form and have the data of the book in question in it?
I have a parent component with the book list and the modal. In the modal component I have the form component.

In the ListBook component I have the buttons to delete and edit :

```
export default class ListBooks extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { error: null, data: [], name: "" }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH_BOOKS)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ data: res.data });
            })
            .catch(errorThrown => {
                this.setState({ error: errorThrown });
            })
    }

    /**
    * Use to delete a book by the number.
    */
   handleDelete = (index) => {
    const id = this.state.data[index].name
    Axios.delete(process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH_BOOKS + id)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
            this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, data: prevState.data.filter((book) => book.name !== id) }))
        })
        .catch(errorThrown => {
            this.setState({ error: errorThrown });
        })
}

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>

                <Container>

                    {data.map((books, index) =>
                        <div key={books.number}>
                            <ListGroup>
                                <ListGroup.Item disabled id={"book-admin" + data[index].number}>{books.number}. {books.name} {books.author}
                                </ListGroup.Item>
                            </ListGroup>
                            <Button variant="outline-warning" size="sm" className="btn-admin-change" id={data.number} onClick={this.props.handleUpdate}>Modifier</Button>
                            <Button variant="outline-danger" size="sm" className="btn-admin-change" onClick={() => this.handleDelete(index)}>Supprimer</Button>

                        </div>
                    )}
                </Container>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In the modal component the button add a new form :

```
function NewBookModal() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
  
    return (
      <>
        <Button variant="dark" size="sm" className="add-new-book-btn" onClick={handleShow}>
          Ajouter une publication
        </Button>
  
        <Modal show={show} onSubmit={handleClose} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Nouvelle publication</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
        <FormNewBook />
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  }
  
export default NewBookModal
```

And finally the Form component :

```
export default class FormNewBook extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
        this.state = { updateTime: false, updateNumber: "", error: null, data: [], number: "", name: "", author: "", format: "", pages: "", paper: "", printing: "", copies: "", price: "", desc_fr: "", desc_en: "", imgCover: "", img1:"", img2:"", img3:"", img4:"", new: false }
    }

    /**
   * Controlled components everywhere.
   */
    handleChange = event => {
        const target = event.target;

        this.setState({
            [target.name]: target.value
        });
    };

    /**
   * Function to POST or PUT the new books. The state boolean updateTime allows to switch between POST or PUT.
   */
    handleSubmit = event => {
        let saisie = this.state;
        event.preventDefault();
        let newBook = {
            number: saisie.number,
            name: saisie.name,
            author: saisie.author,
            format: saisie.format,
            pages: saisie.pages,
            paper: saisie.paper,
            printin: saisie.printing,
            copies: saisie.copies,
            price: saisie.price,
            desc_fr: saisie.desc_fr,
            desc_en: saisie.desc_en,
            imgCover: saisie.imgCover,
            img1: saisie.img1,
            img2: saisie.img2,
            img3: saisie.img3,
            img4: saisie.img4,
            new: saisie.new
        }
        if (this.state.updateTime === false) {
            Axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH_BOOKS, newBook)
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({ modal: true, number: "", name: "", author: "", format: "", pages: "", paper: "", printing: "", copies: "", price: "", desc_fr: "", desc_en: "", img1:"", img2:"", img3:"", img4:"", new: "" })
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(response.data);
                    Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH_BOOKS)
                        .then(response => {
                            this.setState({ data: response.data });
                        })
                        .catch(errorThrown => {
                            this.setState({ error: errorThrown });
                        })
                })
                .catch (errorThrown => {
            this.setState({ error: errorThrown });
        })
    } else {
    Axios.put(process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH_BOOK + "/" + this.state.updateNumber, newBook)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({ modal: true })
            console.log(response);
            Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH_BOOKS)
                .then(response => {
                    this.setState({ data: response.data, updateTime: false, updateNumber: "", number: "", name: "", author: "", format: "", pages: "", paper: "", printing: "", copies: "", price: "", desc_fr: "", desc_en: "", img1:"", img2:"", img3:"", img4:"", new: "" })

                })
                .catch(errorThrown => {
                    this.setState({ error: errorThrown });
                })
        })
        .catch(errorThrown => {
            this.setState({ error: errorThrown });
        })
}
    }

handleUpdate = (event) => {
    let id = event.target.number;
    console.log(id);
    let bookCible = {};
    this.state.data.forEach(book => {
        if (book.number === id) {
            bookCible = book;
        }
    })
    if (bookCible.number !== null || bookCible.number !== undefined) {
        this.setState({ number: "", name: "", author: "", format: "", pages: "", paper: "", printing: "", copies: "", price: "", desc_fr: "", desc_en: "", img1:"", img2:"", img3:"", img4:"", new: "" })
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <>


            <Form className="admin" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Row>
                    <Col xl={1}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="Number">
                            <Form.Label>Numéro</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control as="input" type="number" name="number" value={this.state.number} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Col>

                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="Title">
                        <Form.Label>Titre</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="input" type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="Author">
                        <Form.Label>Auteur</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="input" type="text" name="author" value={this.state.author} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form.Row>

                <Form.Row>
                    <Col xl={2}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="Format">
                            <Form.Label>Format</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control as="input" type="text" name="format" value={this.state.format} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Col>

                    <Col xl={2}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="Pages">
                            <Form.Label>Pages</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control as="input" type="number" name="pages" value={this.state.pages} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Col>
                </Form.Row>

                <Form.Row>
                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="Paper">
                        <Form.Label>Paper</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="input" type="text" name="paper" value={this.state.paper} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="Printing">
                        <Form.Label>Printing</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="input" type="text" name="printing" value={this.state.printing} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form.Row>

                <Form.Row>
                    <Col xl={2}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="Copies">
                            <Form.Label>Copies</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control as="input" type="number" name="copies" value={this.state.copies} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Col>

                    <Col xl={2}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="Price">
                            <Form.Label>Price</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control as="input" type="number" name="price" value={this.state.price} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Col>
                </Form.Row>

                <Form.Row>
                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="DescFr">
                        <Form.Label>Desc fr</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="textarea" rows="4" name="desc_fr" value={this.state.desc_fr} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="DescEn">
                        <Form.Label>Desc En</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="textarea" rows="4" name="desc_en" value={this.state.desc_en} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form.Row>

                <Form.Row>
                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="imgCover">
                        <Form.Label>imgCover</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="input" type="text" name="imgCover" value={this.state.imgCover} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </Form.Group>
                    </Form.Row>
                    <Form.Row>
                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="img1">
                        <Form.Label>img1</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="input" type="text" name="img1" value={this.state.img1} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </Form.Group>
               
                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="img2">
                        <Form.Label>img2</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="input" type="text" name="img2" value={this.state.img2} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="img3">
                        <Form.Label>img3</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="input" type="text" name="img3" value={this.state.img3} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="img4">
                        <Form.Label>img3</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="input" type="text" name="img4" value={this.state.img4} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form.Row>
                <Form.Group controlId="Checkbox">
                    <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="New" name="new" value={this.state.new} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </Form.Group>

                <Button variant="outline-dark" type="submit">
                    Submit
</Button>
            </Form>
        </>
    )
}
};
```

Parent component admin.js :

```
xport default class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { error: null, data: [] }
  }
 

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Accordion>
          <Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
              Publications
      </Accordion.Toggle>
          </Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <Card.Body> <ListBooks /></Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Accordion>

        <NewBookModal />

      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

I'm not an expert in ReactJs and try to learn with this project, but here I'm really stuck and can't find the responses online.
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: whats the value of this.props.handleUpdate in List Books? or where are you calling NewBookModal?

Comment: Undefined, because the function is not in the same component

Comment: in the parent component . I add it in the question

Comment: I am having troubles figuring what gets a modal to pop up: does it at all pop up the way you have it so far?: Out of your update it seems you are calling ListBooks without any properties, however in your ListBooks component you expect to receive a handleUpdate function as a prop and are calling it on click: `onClick={this.props.handleUpdate}`, `<ListBooks />`

Comment: No it doesn't. The modal pops up at first with the button in the NewBookModal with the event handler onClick={handleShow}> but for a new book with a blank form

Comment: For the HandlUpdate, I think what I've done is wrong. It's part from a former project, which is not exactly the same, so it could be fully wrong

Comment: Is there a way, in that configuration to pops the modal up with the form completed and ok to update?

Comment: point is: if it is undefined — it will stay undefined, its not going to propagate on its own if defined in a different scope. What I am getting at is you need to pass starting values to NewBookModal, so that you can further modify and save them and in order to do that you would need to pass argument to the function that further handles NewBookModal popup, so that in that function you could pass along your data to NewBookModal component. Does it make sense?

Comment: `Is there a way, in that configuration to pops the modal up with the form completed and ok to update?` if there is will — there is a way, yet I cant tell what makes a modal pop up. You are saying it does pop up on click, but it appears blank and this a problem you are trying to get help with, right?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: I mean, the form pops up uncompleted, I fill it and submit it to the post request. That part works fine.

Comment: What I would like is re-poping up when I click on edit to update the data

Comment: ok, lets follow this through: what do you click in order for modal to re pop ?

Comment: The button "modifier" with the event onClick={this.props.handleUpdate} Which is wrong and is the first step I'm trying to solve